# If I missed the chance to get a plant in PVZ2 arena, is there any way to get it?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies-2

For example, the plant in season is now buttercup, but during the teleportato mine season I didn't get enough seed packets to unlock it. Does this mean this plant is lost to me forever? Or will the season come back some day? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It seems like certain plants get a relaunch. Every few seasons, you get 4 instead of 1 plant. These 4 plants have already been available in previous seasons. However, such a season does not appear as every 5th season, so not all plants are being repeated.

See [pvz2wiki](https://plantsvszombies.fandom.com/wiki/Arena)(See "seasons list"). As example, stickybomb rice got repeated in season 30, first appeared in season 23. However, there's not yet been a 4-plant-season after teleportatoe, so there might be one soon.

Answer (score 1):

### It's unlikely that you're totally screwed

There are a few ways to get seed packets for a plant whose tournament has passed:

- Usually right after the tournament, packets for that plant are available in the store for a certain number of gems, but usually at an unfavorable rate (i.e. 13 gems for 10 packets).
- Often Penny's Pursuit games will include 1 or more plants from previous tournaments that are highlighted and allow you to collect a bunch of packets for those plants. If you catch the Penny's Pursuit for Teleportato (hasn't occurred at time of writing), you can almost certainly pick up a bunch of packets that way.
- At some point the plant will get re-featured in some fashion. You might see it pop up in a tournament in a more limited scope; for example there might be a tournament focused on the bombard-mint plants and packets for it may become available during that time.